# What is the difference in calculation between a code in C# and Javascript

Tags: javascript, c#

I was looking for an answer for a question from Project Euler and I found one here

http://www.mathblog.dk/triangle-number-with-more-than-500-divisors/

```
int number = 0;
int i = 1;

while(NumberOfDivisors(number) < 500){
    number += i;
    i++;
}

private int NumberOfDivisors(int number) {
    int nod = 0;
    int sqrt = (int) Math.Sqrt(number);

    for(int i = 1; i<= sqrt; i++){
        if(number % i == 0){
            nod += 2;
        }
    }
    //Correction if the number is a perfect square
    if (sqrt * sqrt == number) {
        nod--;
    }

    return nod;
}
```

So I tried to implement the same solution in Javascript but it doesn't give me the same result.

```
var number = 0;
var i = 1;

while (numberOfDivisors(number) < 500) {
  number += i;
  i++;
}

console.log(number);

function numberOfDivisors(num) {
  var nod = 0;
  var sqr = Math.sqrt(num);

  for (i = 1; i <= sqr; i++) {
    if (num % i === 0) {
      nod += 2;
    }
  }

 if (sqr * sqr == num) {
    nod--;
}

  return nod;
}
```

I tested the other code in C# and it gives the right solution. I was wondering if I made a mistake or whether they work differently in some aspect I'm unaware of.

Comment: Did you happen to notice anything in *particular* that differed about the result from the JS version? Was it possibly not an integer? Anything?

Comment: `it gives the right solution` - what is the right solution?

Comment: When you debugged the two code snippets, where EXACTLY did their behaviour differ and EXACTLY how did it differ?

Comment: The first code converts the result of `Sqrt` to `int`, the 2nd does not?

Comment: Since OP couldn't be bothered responding. Correct answer is **76576500**, in OP's code answer is **17297280** (which isn't even a triangle number - so that should've been a clue)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem is that you are testing non-triangle numbers because you forgot one important thing ... scope ...

```
for (i = 1; i <= sqr; i++) {
```

screws your (global) value of `i` ...

see in c# you have

```
for(int i = 1; i<= sqrt; i++){
    ^^^
```

give javascript the same courtesy and try

```
for (var i = 1; i <= sqr; i++) {
     ^^^
```

you should also get the square root as an integer, otherwise you'll be one off in most counts

```
var sqr = Math.floor(Math.sqrt(num));
```

i.e.

```js
var number = 0;
var i = 1;
console.time('took');
while (numberOfDivisors(number) < 500) {
  number += i;
  i++;
}
console.timeEnd('took');
console.log(number);

function numberOfDivisors(num) {
  var nod = 0;
  var sqr = Math.floor(Math.sqrt(num));

  for (var i = 1; i <= sqr; i++) {
    if (num % i === 0) {
      nod += 2;
    }
  }

  if (sqr * sqr == num) {
    nod--;
  }

  return nod;
}
```

(added some timing info for fun)